# Problemas con JUnit y asertos

Tags: java

No entiendo por que me da error el assertEquals. Me pide importar static org.junit.Assert.*, pero como os podéis fijar ya lo hago.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
public class ProductoTest {

    public static final double ERROR_ADMISIBLE = 0.00001;

     @Test
     public void testGetPrecio() {
        Producto CocaCola = new Producto("Coca-Cola", 1.50, "123456789128");
        assertEquals(CocaCola.getPrecio(),1.50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el mensaje de error que aparece en tu IDE.

Comment: The method assertEquals(double, double) is undefined for the type ProductoTest.

Comment: Es extraño. Parece que tu proyecto no está configurado para usar Java 6.